# Calculate all combinations of a series

Tags: javascript, set, combinations

I have a list of items, and each item has a quantity.

```
var items = {
    1: 12,   // we have 12 x item1
    2: 1,    // we have 1 x item2
    3: 1,
    4: 7,
    5: 2,
    6: 2
};
```

Alternatively this could be viewed as:

```
var items = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
             2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6];
```

How would you go about obtaining a list of every combination of these items, keeping in mind that the order is entirely unimportant (and hence `[1,2,3] == [3,2,1]`), and that not every item has to exist in the result.

I suppose the output could look like this:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
...
```

or, even better:

```
{1 : 1}          // 1 x item1
{1 : 2}          // 2 x item1 
{1 : 1, 2 : 1}   // 1 x item1, 1 x item2
{1 : 1, 3 : 1}
....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not every item has to exist in the result?" What sort of results exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that quantity of each item is limited.

I'd go with incremental here:
Start with empty and add item 1 while possible. When done, remove all 1s and add a 2 and start adding ones again. When ones reach capacity, remove them all, add another 2 and start again. When 2s reach capacity, remove them and add a 3. And so on...

Kinda like numbers work.

---

Ok, let's try to code... Hash with incrementing integer keys is an array ;-)
It's easier to assume that first element of the array is the right digit of out 'floating radix' number.

This is javaScript:

```
var limits = [1, 3, 5, 2];

function out(arr){
  var text = '';
  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    text += arr[i] + '.'
  }
  var log = document.getElementById('log');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  log.appendChild(p);
  p.innerHTML = '<span>' + text + '</span>';
}

function generateNextSet(set){
  for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++){
    var amount = set[i];
    if (amount + 1 > limits[i]){
      set[i] = 0;
    } else {
      set[i] = amount + 1;
      return set;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function generateSets(){
  var initial_set = [0, 0, 0, 0]
  var set = generateNextSet(initial_set);
  out(set);
  while (set = generateNextSet(set)) {
    out(set);
  }
};
```

Add a div with id 'log' to the document and somehow start the **generateSets()** method to check out the output.

Comment: Yes, I realised that one approach would be to treat each combination as a mixed-radix number, and then to get them all, you just need to count up from 0 to the maximum number of combinations. This has now lead me to a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759296/converting-a-decimal-to-a-mixed-radix-base-number

Comment: +1 The same idea I had in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759259/calculate-all-combinations-of-a-series/760685#760685

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** After posting this answer, I noticed that an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759259/calculate-all-combinations-of-a-series/759293#759293) had the same approach, but I'll still keep mine around since it's more verbose and even has working code :)

---

If you only had one instance of each item in the original item pool, and your items represented binary digits;

```
var items {
    1 : 1,
    2 : 1,
    4 : 1,
    8 : 1,
    16: 1,
    32: 1
};
```

The problem would be simplified to generating a sequence of all numbers that can be represented by these digits:

- 0 ([ ] - no items)
- 1 ([ 1 ])
- 2 ([ 2 ])
- 3 ([ 2, 1 ])
- 4 ([ 4 ])
- etc.

So, your problem can be viewed as simply asking for the sequence of numbers that can be represented by -- not binary -- but a [mixed-radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) numeral system.

Which means, you could write a counter for this weird numbering system to iterate through values 0 and MAX. So, you'd start with incrementing the least significant digit and carry over to the more significant digit when you've exhausted all the possible values that digit can take.

```
var items = {
    1: 12,   // we have 12 x item1
    2: 1,    // we have 1 x item2
    3: 1,
    4: 7,
    5: 2,
    6: 2
};

var counter = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0
};

function increment(digit) {
    if (digit > 6) {
        return false;
    }

    var value = counter[digit] + 1;

    if (value > items[digit]) {
        counter[digit] = 0;
        return increment(digit + 1);
    }

    counter[digit] = value;

    return true;
}

while (increment(1)) {
    var set = [];

    for (var digit in counter) {
        var value = counter[digit];

        for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            set.push(digit);
        }
    }

    document.write("<div>" + set + "</div>");
}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
1
1,1
1,1,1

---- snip ----

2
1,2
1,1,2

---- big snip ----

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the normal combinations.

For each basic set that has n numbers with a quantity greater than 1, loop through all quantities: [5,6] -> [5,5,6], [5,6,6], [5,5,6,6].

```
[]
[1] -> [1,1], [1,1,1] etc
  [1,2] -> [1,1,2], ...
  [1,3] -> [1,1,3]
  [1,4] -> [1,1,4], ...., [1,4,4], -- all combinations of all multi quantity
[2]
[3]
[4] -> [4,4], [4,4,4] etc
[5] -> [5,5]
[6] -> [6,6]
```

Etc...

Another method (pseudocode):

```
Combinations: {N -> N} -> [[N]]
Combinations(s) == CombinationsX(s, [])

CombinationsX: {N -> N} X [N] -> [[N]]
Combinationsx(s, g) ==
  if s = {} then return []
  else
    {a -> b} = hd s
    ts = tl s
    res = Combinationsx(ts, g) 
    for q in 1..b do
      g = g + [a]
      res = res ++ Combinationsx(ts, g)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

A good resource for [combination generation](http://www.merriampark.com/comb.htm) is the algorithm described by Kenneth H. Rosen in [*Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*](http://www.mhhe.com/math/advmath/rosen/). Many problems can make use of this general algorithm and it's good to have it in your toolbox.

Comment: the link to your reference is dead now