# Mixed Radix real world usage

Tags: math, radix

I am working my way through an algorithm book, and there was a brief mention of using [Mixed Radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) to store a date. There was only one article in stackoverflow, and I could find little else about it on the internet (specifically converting a [mixed radix to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759296/converting-a-decimal-to-a-mixed-radix-base-number)).

Is Mixed Radix a concept in use in the real world? If so, what are examples of real world usages?

Comment: I don't know, but is "201208290918" an example of this?

Comment: @Thilo no, but 290918 could have been (month and year are not all the same multiple of days :-)

Comment: Take a look at the stack overflow link above "mixed radix to decimal" for code examples, and some pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is used a lot, especially for date/time. You also have it in non-metric units of measurement, miles-yards-feet-inches, pounds-ounces, etc.

Comment: Do you convert and store as a decimal?

Comment: Yes. And you create methods to get the various parts. Just check out the implementation of the Date class in any language for an example.