# Find all possible variations of a string of letters

Tags: string, combinations, combinatorics

Newb programmer here, I'm most familiar with Python but also learning C and Java, so either of 3 would be fine.
What I have is a string of letters, say:

> ABXDEYGH

However say,

> X is possible to be M and N.
>   Y is possible to be P and Q.

In this example, I would like basically to print all possible variations of this string of letters.
Like:

> ABMDEPGH
>   ABNDEPGH
>   ABMDEQGH
>   ABNDEQGH

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate all combinations of a series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759259/calculate-all-combinations-of-a-series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to a simple problem of permutations. What you care about is the part of the text that can change; the variables. The rest can be ignored, until you want to display it.

So your question can be more simply stated: What are all the possible permutations of 1 item from set `X` and another item from set `Y`? This is known as a *cross-product*, sometimes also simply called a [product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Here's a possible Python solution:

```
import itertools

x = set(['M', 'N'])
y = set(['P', 'Q'])

for items in itertools.product(x, y)
    print 'AB{0}DE{1}GH'.format(*items)
```

Note that the `print ''.format()` command uses the "unpack arguments" notation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-and-do-for-python-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

why dont you write two loops. one to replace all possible characters with X and one for Y.

```
foreach(char c in charSet1){
   // replaces X
   foreach(char ch in charSet2){
     // replace Y 
   }

}
```